# Getting the Last Row in a Spreadsheet Embedded in a UserForm

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am trying to get the last row and last column in a spreadsheet that I have embedded in a userform.

I have been treating it exactly like a regular spreadsheet (refering to cells, ranges...etc) and it has been working perfectly until I tried to get the last row or column. Any idea if the syntax is correct?

I end up getting Run-time error '91'

```
LastRow = Hold_Summary_UserForm.Spreadsheet1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Comment: How is `LastRow` declared?

Comment: LastRow As Long

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail if the sheet has no content: you should split it up into multiple steps

```
Dim f As Range, LastRow As Long

Set f = Hold_Summary_UserForm.Spreadsheet1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

If Not f Is Nothing Then
    LastRow = f.Row
Else
    'no content...
End If
```

Comment: The sheet will always have content that I input during the initialization of the userform. The user will only add more information to the sheet and click a button to perform another task. With that button, I search for the last row to capture their input but I am running in the run-time error.

Comment: Do you still get that error if you use the code I posted?

Comment: Sure do. In this case, f is nothing. And there is content in the spreadsheet. This is an embedded spreadsheet in a userform. Not sure if there is a special syntax to find cells in that type of control.

Comment: If you look at other properties of the sheet, do they have the expected values?  Things like `UsedRange`, etc.